# Incompatible argument with spawnv

Tags: c, pointers, char

I have a little problem. I made a simple program in C using Eclipse CDT, that takes other exe's with their command line as parameters, and then executes these commands in a certain order to compare how long they take to run. This is the part of the code I'm having trouble with:

```
char ** strpare1;
strcpy(s1,exelist[algoritmo1].cifrado);
strpare1 = split(s1);

start = clock();
spawnv( P_WAIT, strpare1[0], strpare1 );
end = clock();
cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

"split()" is a function that splits the string in a vector of strings, separated by spaces. It takes a "char *" as argument, and returns a "char **".

When I try to compile this, it says the third argument of "spawnv" is passed from an incompatible pointer. I think it's related to the fact that I need to use a "const * char" instead of a "char **" or something like that, but I'm really not sure if I can convert it somehow. It compiles anyways, and the program works fine, but that error bothers me. I need to give the code to a teacher, and I want it to be free of errors. Is there a way to fix that? or at least suppress the warning.

Comment: "or something like that". Your compiler tells you exactly what type was expected, and what he got.

Comment: What is the exact compiler error? What is the signature of spawnv?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm using Eclipse CDT. It seems to be using GCC to compile, and the error is not specific at all. It's in Spanish, and it roughly translates to "Warning: the argument 3 of 'spawnv' is passed from an incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]". The program works as expected, I just want to get rid of that error if possible.

According to this page (https://users.pja.edu.pl/~jms/qnx/help/watcom/clibref/src/spawn.html), spawnv uses a "const char" for the second argument, and a "char *const" for the third argument.

Comment: does your source code include the statement: `#include <process.h>`  If not, then the default parameter types (usually 'int') is used.